# добавит закладку на рабочий стол в мобильном

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

недавно я заметил на aliexpress есть некая оповещения типа добавит закладку на рабочий стол:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

интересно а как это можно сделать?

Comment: подробная инструкция от гугла:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/

Comment: как вариант спасибо, но это не совсем тот.